# code creates different different results Reading csv file and txt file - java

Tags: java, csv, readfile

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
try {

  String line = reader.readLine();
  while (line != null) {

    result.append(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
    if (line != null) {
      result.append("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Hello, I want to read a csv file and save each line into an array but my code reads an empty line after each text line. If I save the csv as txt and try the same code it works. -.- You find the csv file here https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wgl24tikm5xj6f/2408201406022015.csv?dl=0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to read a csv (thus text) file created under some platform in a program run in another one? e.g a MS Windows text file in Linux or Mac OSX?

Comment: Check your line endings

Comment: the csv file is created automatically  by a weather station

Comment: @thermite what do you mean?

Comment: two lines for example: 
1 24.08.2014 11:37:12 30 23.2 49 16.3 71 1011.8 1004.5 0.0 0.3 NE 11.1 16.3 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
2 24.08.2014 12:07:12 30 23.5 48 17.7 65 1011.7 1004.4 0.7 1.0 N 11.1 17.7 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

Comment: @dave4422 I meant exactly what michael said in his answer. Line endings and really mess with you if your not careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Javadoc for BufferedReader:

> A line is represented by zero or more characters followed by '\n',
>   '\r', "\r\n" or the end of the reader

When I look at the csv file you specified in a hex editor, I see \n\r pairs which is weird.  Normally, you'd see the lines terminated with \r\n.

That explains why the Reader is interpreting things with an extra empty line.

Use the String.trim() method to trim leading and trailing whitespace and then check the length of the resulting String to see whether or not to append it to your StringBuilder.

Also, be sure to close your BufferedReader in a finally block when you're done with it.

Something like:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(in);

    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            result.append(line);
            result.append('\n');
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {

}
finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        try {reader.close();} catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}

System.out.println(result.toString());
```